# Linux laptop freezes sometimes

Tags: linux, memory, cpu, freeze

I have a fanless laptop (Acer TM B115M — Intel Pentium N3520 Quad-core 2.17 GHz, 4 GB RAM), and under Gnome and KDE, it sometime freezes. I tried a number of distros and it still freezes. It doesn't accept any input (not even magic sysrq), and I can't ping it from another computer either. I installed OpenBox + Tint2 and it didn't freeze yet. At first I suspected it might be bug, or my CPU might be overheating (possibly due to the fancy desktop effects of gnome and kde) or bad ram. Moreover, journalctl doesn't complain about anything after a freeze and hard restart.
I would appreciate any help to pinpoint the exact cause. Thanks!

Comment: If you can ping, then can you `ssh` into it from network? You need a running `sshd`.

Comment: @ott-- OP wrote "can't ping it from another computer".

Comment: no, I cannot ping it.

Comment: Ok, I misread that. Have you checked the logfiles in /var/log like messages, syslog, boot? You can also redirect all syslog output to a remote pc.

Comment: I checked journalctl. Nothing out of the oridinary. Last messages were either from NetworkManager or gdm.

Comment: Never mind, it's a kernel bug, apparently many users experience it: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051