# How to get a clue why my Linux computer is freezing

Tags: linux, freeze, logging

## tl;dr

My laptop computer running Linux is freezing randomly. What system tools can help to figure out what the problem is?

> DISCLAIMER: I hope my question is not considered as a duplicate since most of the *computer is freezing* topics attend to running Windows OS.

## The long story

My laptop computer is an *Acer TravelMate B115-M* which is about two years old by now. At first I was running Windows 8.1 for a long time and it was running very stable. But a year ago I finally switched to Linux trying out several distributions. Since then my system keeps freezing randomly.

This issue I am facing from the beginning when I switched to Linux. That's why I think it is not a hardware issue (although I tried to solve it by updating the system BIOS). Since then I was running Ubuntu and Kubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu Mate 16.04 and now Linux Mint 18 for several months. Started with Kernel 3.13 now Kernel 4.4 it is.

### The symptom

By freezing I mean that the mouse pointer stops moving, no keyboard keys are working and the sound stops playing but the screen does not turn black. Also the emergency reboot by the [magic SysRq key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) Alt+Print+B does not reboot the system. So I have to power cycle the system.

By random freezing I mean that there are days when my system is freezing up to two times within an hour. But also there is a time when my system is running for weeks not freezing at all. That's why it is very difficult for me to diagnose this issue.

### System tools

I tried to get closer to that issue by investigating some logs. So I turned on persistence for `journald` and waited until the next freeze. After rebooting I took a look into the logs of the previous boot log by issuing the command `sudo journalctl -b -1` and went straight to the end. Unfortunately there were no clues for any freeze or crash to find. No errors and no warnings!

So now I am asking for help. Does anyone have some helping hints to get behind the freezes? What system tools I can use to do further investigation by myself?

Thanks in advance!

## EDIT

Just after asking my question I found [another question](https://superuser.com/q/1028981/287193) facing the same issue. There the user named @spacelander points to a [known bug regarding Intel Bay Trail CPUs](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051) in the linux kernel.

Comment: More precisely the user *Wolfgang M. Reimer* at the [bug tracker link](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051#c434) provides a script to temporarily disable the problematic C-states of the cpu causing the freezes. Found at [Heise Online Newsticker](https://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/Patch-stabilisiert-Linux-auf-Atom-Celerons-3337456.html).

Answer (score 2):

Edit /etc/defaults/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

Run

```
update-grub
shutdown -r now
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? In my case, it made the WiFi non-functional on rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

Although you have provided details about the symptoms, it it probably is still not enough data for a correct diagnosis. Other users may ask you for some logs.

However, I frequently experienced the same issue on my laptop. Turns out the culprit was a USB HDD I had connected.

Apparently, depending on your system settings, USB peripherals such as HDDs and dongles can freeze the user interface when transferring data. COnsequently, your system becomes completely unresponsive for a while, clicks do not work (neither mousemovement), and becaouse your keyboard gets ignored as well, no maigc key combination will work.

Now, I don't recall exactly why, but I belive it had something to do with the way I had configured my swap. You may take a look at [this article](https://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/tales-from-responsivenessland-why-linux-feels-slow-and-how-to-fix-that).

I might be pointing you in the wrong direction, so discretion is advised ;) Good luck!

Comment: My laptop doesn't have /etc/sysctl.conf file. Do you know where it might be? or atleast it's equivalent. I'm using Manjaro OS (Arch based distro)

Comment: Just google the mame of your distribución along "swapiness". I'm sure there will be several referencia pointing you to the right conf file ;)